Question on volume of subgroup of p-adic group
In P.Cartier's article "representation of the p-adic group" something is written at the very beginning of IV that I don't quite understand.
Let $G$ be a $p$-adic reductive group. Let $\Gamma$ be $K,N,M$ or $G$ (where $K$ is a maximal compact, $N$ a unipotent and $M$ a Levi). Next, it is claim that we can normalize the Haar measure such that the volume of $\Gamma\cap K$ is equal to $1$. In other words, the volumes of $K\cap \Gamma$ are all equal.
Why is this true?

Are you sure the article claims that the normalization will work for all choices of $\Gamma$ "simultaneously"? That would indeed be strange. I guess (I don't have the article in front of me) it first chooses one possible $\Gamma$, and then normalizes the Haar measure with respect to that.
